# Which data structure for fast changing objects with common properties?

Tags: python, class, architecture

When working with objects in a certain manner, my code tends to get unreadble. I am looking for some ideas to change my architecture to make it more readable.

The problem usually looks like this:

```
# Attributes: sex, name, job, hobbies
myObjects = [Obj1, Obj2, Obj3]
tmpObjects = filterMales(myObjects)
# after filtering: myObjects = [Obj1, Obj2]
# Attributes after filtering: name, job, hobbies
resolvedObjects = estimatedIncome(tmpObjects)
# Attributes after estimation: name, income, hobbies
```

So i create initial objects list that changes in size. Furthermore, the values and attributes of its objects changes. Its quite difficult to get an idea of how the list and each object looks after each step of the processing.

My first approach: Initially i used the same name for the list of each processing step. I switched to using something like "intialObjectList", "tmpObjectList" and "resolvedObjectList". Thats more readable, but overall it still sucks.

My second idea: Use an abstract class "object" that has 'name' and 'hobbies' and create separate class for maleObjects and resolvedObjects.

My third idea: Create a big class that has all the attributes and simply leave out the ones that are no longer used.

I don't really like any of the three ideas, which one do you like best? Can someone provide a better solution or a different pattern to approach the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just to use meaningful names for those lists?

As far as I can see in your example, all lists seems to contain same "things", people, so I'd keep the exactly same objects even if some attributes are calculated in the last step to avoid splitting objects into objects that doesn't have a clear purpose.

In this case, tmpObjects and resolvedObjects from your example would be exactly the same lists, since no new objects would be created but updated.

In terms of performance, instead of mind about having unused attributes or not when instantiating objects, I would think about how those list are iterated and how many times. I would suggest to use generators and to concatenate operations with them, having another generator as a result to perform all operations at once. In Python 3 could be something like this:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, sex: str, name: str, job: str, hobbies: list):
        self.sex = sex
        self.name = name
        self.job = job
        self.hobbies = hobbies

        # Additional attribute
        self.income = None

def calculate_income(x: Person) -> Person:
    x.income = 100
    return x


# Person objects have name, sex, job and hobbies attributes.
people_set = [
    Person('m', 'Marcos', 'teacher', ['tennis']),
    Person('f', 'Ana', 'developer', ['music', 'art']),
    Person('m', 'Nico', 'doctor', ['football', 'cine'])
]

male_subset_gen = filter(lambda x: x.sex == 'm', people_set)

male_subset_with_income_gen = map(lambda x: calculate_income(x), male_subset_gen)
```

Once at this point, the resulting generator can be evaluated in different ways, using list at once:

```
male_subset_with_income = list(male_subset_with_income_gen)
```

or iterating over it:

```
for person in male_subset_with_income_gen:
    # Do whatever
    pass
```

But in both cases, the original data set people_set is iterated only once.